# Schedule a stored procedure to run periodically?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a task to update a table, periodically, using a stored procedure. Could you let me know if it is possible to schedule periodic tasks and to run any system command within stored procedure?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) to create jobs that run at regularly-scheduled intervals. One of the job step types is executing a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 3rd party tool for my schedules. To be honest, it's not a great deal better than Sql Server Agent, but there are few perks to it. It's called 
[System Scheduler](http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm).